# Modifying static byte array in a compiled ELF executable

Tags: c, elf

I have a scenario where i wan't to provide a utility for my users to create a compressed self-extracting executable (similar to UPX but with other properties).

This is currently done by compressing an executable and then generating c source code containing a byte array containing the executable:

```
#include "exdata.c"
```

**exdata.c:**

```
const unsigned char compressedData[] = { 0x28,0xB5... }
const size_t uncompressedSize =  3697664;
```

The problem is that i want to be able to change this byte array without recompiling the program to enable my users to use the utility without require them to install a c compiler.

Can i use a "placeholder" byte array, find that value in the compiled binary and replace it with the real data? Or can i somehow add the data to a custom "segment" and just modify that?

Edit: I found a python library called lief that seem to be able to modify segment content but modifying a segment with more data than what’s already there seems very complicated as all other segments and addresses + offsets needs to be handled

Comment: It seems that you would need to be able to instruct whatever compression method you are using to exclude the byte array from the process. Then you could patch it. Patching into a compressed stream and getting a predicable outcome does not seem viable.

Comment: I don't think you can, but you can probably add a custom segment or something. @500-InternalServerError I understand the content of the array is compressed, not the executable into which the array is inserted

Comment: The TL;DR: If the compressed file is (e.g.) `zipdata`, and your executable is `myinstall`, you can just put them in a [docker] container. Then, when running, `myinstall` can just read and decompress `zipdata` and store it where you want. It's easy to update and replace files in a container.

Comment: @user253751 you are correct, the "wrapper" executable is not compressed

Comment: @CraigEstey that is an alternative, however ideally want to avoid docker for convenience and compile times

Comment: One thing you can do is hardcode an address and add a segment at that address later - maybe with a linker script telling it not to put anything a certain distance after that address. However I'm not sure if any operating system requires randomized addresses (ASLR) as a security feature. If it does you might be able to add an entry to whatever table helps the program know all the randomized addresses.

Comment: another possibility is to just haphazardly append the data to the end of the file, and open /proc/self/exe to read it (you'd have to skip to the end of the normal part of the file)

Comment: Do you want it to work on 32bit executable, 64 bit or both?

Comment: @Nierusek 64 bit but both ARM64 and x86-64

Answer (score 2):

I think gcc and objcopy can solve a lot of your problem:

- Put the default compressed image in its own section using gcc's `__attribute__` extension
- Make a file with the user's compressed image.
- a user script runs objcopy to replace your section with the user's file

```
$ more replaceable_contents.c 
#include <stdio.h>

struct {
    unsigned char sz;
    const char data[];
} datablob __attribute__((section("COMPRESSEDDATA"))) = {12, "Hello World!"};

int global_counter = 0;


int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {

    for (int i;i<argc;i++) {
        printf("printing %d characters: ", datablob.sz);
        printf("%.*s\n", datablob.sz, datablob.data);
    }
}

$ gcc replaceable_contents.c && ./a.out 2
printing 12 characters: Hello World!
printing 12 characters: Hello World!

$ more text.txt
2This is a test of the emergency compression system

$ objcopy --update-section COMPRESSEDDATA=text.txt a.out a2.out
objcopy: a2.out: section .bss lma 0x201020 adjusted to 0x201044

$ ./a2.out 2
printing 50 characters: This is a test of the emergency compression system
printing 50 characters: This is a test of the emergency compression system
```

Answer (score 1):

> @CraigEstey that is an alternative, however ideally want to avoid docker for convenience and compile times –
> Richard

Okay, so *no* container. But, many commercial installers use a `sh` script as the initial extractor.

Here is a format that I've developed for my own use:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash -
# ovcbin/ovcext.sh -- shell based extractor
#
# this is a self extracting archive
#
# INSTALL:
# (1) save this block to a file (e.g.) /tmp/archive
# (2) create a directory (e.g.) /tmp/extract
# (3) cd to /tmp/extract
# (4) For a dry run, if you wish to see what the archive contains, type:
#       bash /tmp/archive
# (5) To actually extract the archive, type:
#       bash /tmp/archive -go
# (6) This will create the following subdirs under /tmp/extract:
#       hello_package

function ovcopt()
{
    local opt
    local match
    local tmp="/tmp/ovcopt.$$"

    cp /dev/null $tmp

    for opt in $*
    do
        match=$(_ovcopt $opt)
        ovcdbg "ovcopt: TRY match=$match opt=$opt"
    done

    source $tmp

    rm -f $tmp
}

function _ovcopt
{
    local opt=$1
    local sym
    local match=0

    case $opt in
        -*)
            sym=$(echo $opt | sed -e s/-/opt_/ -e '/=/!s/$/=1/')
            ovcdbg "ovcopt: EVAL opt='$opt' sym='$sym'"
            echo "$sym" >> $tmp
            match=1
        ;;
    esac

    echo "$match"
}

function ovcext()
{
    local file=$1
    local opt_chmod
    local opt_b64
    local opt_z
    local dir
    local found=0
    local go=0

    ovcopt $*

    ovcdbg "ovcext: DEBUG_CAE opt_go='$opt_go'"

    if [ -n "$opt_go" ]; then
        go=1
    else
        exit 99
    fi

    while [ 1 ]
    do
        if [ -e "$file" ]; then
            found=1

            if [ -n "$opt_f" ] ; then
                echo "file already exists -- $file (overwriting!)"
                break
            fi

            echo "file already exists -- $file (rerun with -f to force)"
            go=0
            file=/dev/null
            break
        fi

        if [ $go -gt 0 ]; then
            echo "extracting file $file ..."
            dir=$(dirname $file)
            mkdir -p $dir
            break
        fi

        echo "extracting $file (DRY RUN)"
        file=/dev/null
        break
    done

    if [ -n "$zipflg_spl" ]; then
        base64 -d | $zipflg_cmd -d > $file
    else
        cat > $file
    fi

    if [ $go -ne 0 ]; then
        if [ -n "$opt_chmod" ]; then
            chmod $opt_chmod $file
        fi
    fi
}

function ovcdbg()
{

    if [ -n "$ZPXHOWOVC" ]; then
        echo "$*" 1>&2
    fi
}

ovcopt $*
zipflg_spl=1; zipflg_cmd="gzip";

ovcext hello_package/hello.c -b64 -zgzip << '%%%EOF%%%'
H4sICO3/Y2QCA292Y2V4dF96aXBfMQBTzsxLzilNSVWwKS5JyczXy7Dj4srMK+HKTczM0yjLz0zR
5Krm4uIsKAIKpmkoZaTm5OQrlOcX5aTE5ClpWgOlilJLSovyFAysuWq5AKqxSQ1OAAAA
%%%EOF%%%

ovcext hello_package/hello -b64 -zgzip -chmod=755 << '%%%EOF%%%'
H4sICO3/Y2QCA292Y2V4dF96aXBfMADtXH1sHEcVn927893G9vkuThM7Ds21dYJb6jvbSVynzced
449zcT5IHJoAyWZ9t7aPnG/N3l5iFyRCU1BNvwIqBfEhRQiJ/IX6B0URCJoqIUUqoFRCInyJglKU
8tG6fFRQaI73Zmf2btd7cWhRBdI+2ff2/ea9mTdvZndndnbn44OjQ6IgEE4i2UZQSkaSVE4y/O/D
lgpgfaQefm8jt5I6kP1VekmStPEpkdh4iOn5mN0Zhp8Rkza+hulxLlRxP6mmpI33sUTOSaRiF6iS
Casf599nBXBebUezijE8lrTxJNNPuthhbCJxBm9L2vgKVu8W0W4nMrsYs4sxfc4vsXI45/H0s/8L
LL8LLI6cDzC9gSp9pD0vGVk8XsPqt4bVi/MtTG+Lw+59YFdHbpx42Pey8mrFZYHVi3Me1kQ+N967
MZHPduZzhdJs52xfb2fvxnhRi/dQnyJMd3jXfqt/iVU+r2AYph9r/sMjVw53PPDM2fDwifVtj838
6LNzArMXyH9G9fC/vEZ93fB4VVeyEdQvg9XpJTMlo0hkGQG5aCi6IU8ruQIZHh3p3yH3xHvimyB1
clorsFTZ7Dcii5dA68DjXVqdkzD1ViYvbDfjXFcVH3p+V+G+KrwlaeLBtxAbjzzyyCOPPPLII488
8uh/i/7SdPMb6ZN/DKUfDrycICT9yXOGWL6UPnkhdJ6mlzf9FuDyuivw27Q2CUcoT2HSyy+Wy2W0
7/7TyPwLh9Pzv02fvLKwZ2zkuXNPRZMk/dyzScqeWw+sfNMDYPfXU6h/fiLetPZBmv2psx0wwUhv
xV+j+SxC6IL0DALlFydOnZ+oKGP536P6n3iFsmev+dLzC+lnr25PCxfTL1wzolYOQZaD0x7LP7H1
9gROjZr3p+dfuno/1OJiYBUgwqHzp9z0//BpVHwmAlPiq/+6Vi7TQg6db1o7YMYvdd/I/E9T7x+Z
fz21PzX/Zmps9NF137yTkP3pRzuR7xu9/SWM8dXHwTj97Js+Y233L5rWnsBsRuffGJ1/fWD+1VR5
xS/TJ88L6c2/Kv0e4//BQ6kPpQ6lDqfkap9o/KrbzWopjzzyyCOPPPLII4888sgjjzyqTYJtFRBm
9mo+r8WOa3o+S4Q23z19xFwT9C+Uyx8D3g58DPgYcHwKsOy1cvlriAO/APwJ4A2Cud5K879/LxFm
I0JbQzB0SjDXJXFN/wevlss4CScDwQhiXfB/BbAAs2sn5lr1CcBiCIQjQ+GWe5vqj4dOkO2r77lj
Qztd0sS88vB/GPy5CYFUOPIpcUdj3R4okOXxCPwfgHQV04fCkcfFwXDLY77BcOxR/2C445FAOtz1
qbp0uO9kcDicLIT7UuGuVLijPxzrD7f0hyP94RD1+yfoz0LFR4888sgjjzzyyCOPPPLIo/9nikWT
lC+w96Kr37tGauCKLL2RiWeZXStPZu/ztjGZv6e8mvEWlr7Gkf63a2WNyj4znc+1HmIyf+e4g8nL
mLyV8XqeP+M3OepnvdvK3msVHfp83hpkfBWPiz9pwxdY+dzvLsYlR37XymZ9LjH9MpN5PBeYfJGl
v+Ptvc293N5IBR/esePuWMfwrv23x/riG+LdsZ6u7s1dPT0bYh171WwsrRgm3tlzO41HhFVwONUu
bFC6rW8JtEglZk4dbSmdmb5FOqsqDzFQJzCZyTgcrPQPU+eO4d33kTsGq/oRw2k3aLJh7ykaSuao
nMkrxSlCmu36mQl5RtcMNWPktAI6u9JuS1/WPnBATu3bN7h3bGT3rn1V5wrLY2g3pAwdJGWy2J+g
r6rvm9gtIdv5Z+rV4TvmUUCjdl3Td11V8rnJQq14zrA4lrx4vv14Qh8uOeLppsOvmyuvo8Ovpeei
tXVOMPv10drnS5KlPR3977ev7222b422o/3mRtre2b7iO9C+Tzvi+VZ1eNu3XacP8Lb/PuN3Wveq
kK3db6pxXX9T5N/qhITHMQ5xALaK7oYiPuUVL6/ajDfIUPBB8MPnD84D84d8AvyBLAbfi0yoC1Ap
gB+yBPyBXMEAk8BLmME3MOXJVnwcK34Njz/fhsd1oc8QaonPhYN4HHoDfi77u0Pt4JB0AAT/hiB9
Oittw0J7pYdRSyphyl1UiEivYkofFVqk9ShspkJMuhfV7qZCh/QkptxDhS4JP43xb6FCH70z+7dS
ISk1YHySVEhLz6NNigp7pFtQrZ8KByT03z+wEgN3RPoWqg2t2AHClLQeM0hTr2ek32DKCBUMCbuc
/976IrBZ6RUUdi7fA+yE9Caq7Wq6D4QHpDUo7A6NQD4npV+j2vuaDoLwkIR9wX+w8ePATkkfRbUP
rspCyhekcyh8qFUD4bSUQeEQdeeM9ADaHJbwK72npI9girysE8dl0ssoHKG+nZM2oTAeKoHNBSJe
wzYMtn4Fx1HbMYP3hOujArZYn4i/mNCADYZ+NW42B2ChLhDqZ6majIffpYcfFpnuJ7luMwn/ApPm
w5+huWFjh3vx8NMUCV/G7B42j3G8FFzdgF42vADARRGvL8HvUMsvYOLzqLYafoJtqzE1chgyF/yC
6nI2CF8mQlRYF26u94XbwlFheTACFz9xJfGF766/p35z/Qhcn3ztpL5+G2hAxZvgEGLBEDjF6hBB
reB6gizULPjC9fWmtQCA1FiVWR8YL6vkDkFpBmELDIYbBGGkGfUbb4F8EpAU3lhluL0VlZqwz0Xi
ZHsrT3l360gzup1sebIfh9QL9PT/MVZN+Ge4EX4F9rWakCgVdfw6LgGX88RsX6/cu7FTV7NTimF+
KpfoS+QKmXwpqxKqyoTEeM4oLkYSxtyMasfZolA8g5EtGtmsOhGfwqKpKhyKCOuljCEPjYwOAgA3
h8oRWOQ0OISrUXGuKKu6ns8VDdOMwMVEEnnrrQyIowHpdEA4KIpQQ3lktzxempDVQpbIWj4raxMT
RdWguRQgG4IKReWYSjWKU5puxPByVMzdr8oGTc1rcFU3D4/rOUOVZwwwm8grk0XCsx9XiiqRpxX9
qKqbKNwGsmapE7qq6moR9fDLwdiO7ruWHALHOqeNUkHdOqmCk7kMiIqemdpqfrAY65zEgFDv0TmS
1wqT1Gs5U9LljJYvTReoExhAUioU4X4EBWSmFLO+pp9EptVFtyp1MytSKpSKaranUhGsshkcKzcs
j35TaFUQm4TI8oyS3UQtM1pWzRwzTPdsdpXyaISwUXo3YozxCDm4mjOrcDyXVeWsYihmrOEOW5ox
vcQ+UWANAa5OQ2kVh816HDOU8bzK29xqatO80o8gk1xeLWhWH4WstZJBElPatJrIKGpiBuqn6sfU
hHZMHy9kEkbx6HFNP3oDcyMfdHL+PbIdF63vau24j1xxxf3WfNaOB6x5rB2vs+a7djzoOk/0wZjg
kisuWfNUO77Mms/a8frKd9E2vIHEXPFGa25nx8PWGNaON1W+n7bhEet7YzseJQdc8eXW8wU73mw9
V7DjK1znuT64X/DvYe34Suv5gB1fBe674S2k3RVvrdGvVpOOI276bTX019TA31UDv7kGvnYRZn7f
/lrZidPnKWKjNdfmtLMGrjB8xoHPMbzkwD9Xo9zT9EbXaM1vOH2V4U858KcZvuDAn6d1q7QLf97y
c3q8uJ/g7RTziTn6bSPeYl36252Cu/8ba+B0fwCIQ9KR/xjDn47eWHzy1J8o2XLL4v7jpn8/rfjy
RfV9mOaz+Lx4guk76/t1ii8+T79N81l8vuD+BMuxvaL253g4gIu5nEcvCu7fy/+ZvjOyatH59XPU
FxdfZ/5RIx/cZyHiUu460f17/I2AR8UmEnLUN4V41XXM2kdBNOvL21dl+CkatRbS4Sj3COpXnS88
PjfzfBieYPisaObjjMODTN85Ap6n/q9aVO4HaLku1/kbGEbG45U/czuGjG50xzUSVwoFbTxXkHOF
nAH3YIdMRwoWBlNtI5eBWz2Mf6p17Ti1geyLRmliAtRgyKROwv1e1WVjWs7AuETFTRKymjyZ18aV
vJw1NL0oK6VZktGmZ/KqoWbjd/X03eWuBKOGQk5WdF2Zg5IMfY5M6Mo0jFZK09NzYFIl0UrYVPlQ
Q81PdNIaavsq1QBwURgqGBs0De1N7RyUB3cNyDJItgIgeeDgrtTOkR32FLrXA0AwDJUH0yyH9MBe
Ig+P7u5Pjcq7h4b2DY7JY6n+0UGZ7x+RKZZoVemmEsmkbQ8J1RyaOTeacGjRAZxVum3bCUgravKU
UsjmzeEbHdbJOP6sLh8rQeRs3mxaBUaOrKlncmAmjxeLLHtzSCqP7dzBQkPixblpGAcCN3STT/Ej
GIuq+gyJFzRDjaf6RzoNZZJJk4VSfLyUy2c7c9DvUJrCZ1Lx7FwB8jM5DIppyjEY9OMjqWpBhjTw
VUFFdjSTN7BIqEjcUGfhlwY1rms0hnF1ivWYqaxekUwLs/1MC34MGSvTOeghk5pBf8wCzMwgICQO
nXgaehupVCauGIaeGy8Z0PHjWXW8NAm5KYXJipgrTGhW0vi4rh7jEpzBKj/Gqr99amP3VL5+Utm/
h9jWdYhj/YjTbWwthdtX9qth6xKL7m126nbY83H3FQa0L2GP7wW+Xi5r3J6Pz0M+u/8Bx/oUp11s
rUl0rEd1MPsjDK9jdQ851oXeT+x71PDx/kM++3pWrfgdZmtJ3J7PCy767P5y/0UHP8rWprjM5w+X
fPb4O/23xhUspqJjPWzBZ18Pc8aP1/9BZt/vWF+L+e16AfY82Gn/GKnssVS9Hsk3vmlbov3nHfZ8
fhOLuPe/iIM/4bC39stiCiXB3Z7TFx32fBxzlj2YblzC/9OO86+yL5X7+edsvzMO+8q+T6a8ZYny
v+Ww5/O0A8z+6hLln4P/cNV6rLUPVNxdP+TgP2TrDz7HenLLDdpfJva9jqx9tuKV8Wv1OlLI0Y6/
YfXn9nweuZBwb29n+b9z2Fvj5y73/ue0f9Vhz8e1sS739nJeP/7G8uL2fFzZfoP2bzCsy4Fz+ztr
2HOOawrBqnQ+H97D7A8Ert//WgX3/ajObLJff2r531HD/jKzF3zXt99Yw/5nfSb/8RLl99ew/7r5
lJ38dQn7XYJ7/L90t8ll8frxt107Fk38oW+wxsEn05tdrr8Sse8TZvVTtsHc58Tr+x+tYf+VIZMf
FK5vv+zfyzPiKLlQAAA=
%%%EOF%%%
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple stupid way to do this.

1. Make the executable know its length. Easy way is to have `const` and build, measure, build again. It's a pain for automation though.
2. Concatenate the compressed stream to the executable.
3. In the executable source, open /proc/self/exe, seek to the appointed byte and start reading.

I have done this with exactly these steps and provided a small tool to do 2. I would call this tool a step 4.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Will this result in an additional file read (the disk in the VM is very slow)?

Comment: @Richard: No. Paging has a similar cost.

Comment: I’m getting about twice the startup time with this approach so it’s not feasible

Comment: @Richard: Yeah you probably would. Writing the exe to /tmp and running it is going to totally suck unless you use case is like mine and it's importing something more like 100mb and you're gong to use most of it on every invocation.